# while loops for choice input & reading files

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input, filenotfoundexception

I'm very new to coding in python and would much appreciate the help!

**Trying to achieve:**

Choice input to either use the calculator or to open a file (that has appended all the calculations)

Use defensive coding for the file does not exist

Prompt the user to enter the name of the file again
**Issues**

The first input (process_choice) is not taking me to the options

OPEN FILE to read: reading the file & showing `fileNotFoundError at the same time`

```
from pathlib import Path

file = open('calculatortextfile.txt' , 'a')

process_choice = str(input("Enter 'C' to use calculator or 'F' to open file: ")).upper

#CALCULATOR OPTION
while True:
        
    if process_choice == "C": 

       
            try:
                num1 = float(input("Please enter a number:"))
                num2 = float(input("Please enter another number: "))

                operator = input("Please enter the operator (+, -, *, /): ")   


                if operator == "+":
                    calculation = num1 + num2
                    entry = ("{} + {} = {}".format(num1,num2,calculation))  
                    print(entry) 

                elif operator == "-":
                    calculation = num1 - num2
                    entry = ("{} - {} = {}".format(num1,num2,calculation)) 
                    print(entry)

                elif operator == "*":
                    calculation = num1 * num2
                    entry = ("{} * {} = {}".format(num1,num2, calculation)) 
                    print(entry)   

                elif operator == "/":
                    calculation = num1 / num2
                    entry = ("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, calculation))
                    print(entry)

                else:   
                    print("You have not entered a valid operator, please try again.")
                    continue

                file.write(str(num1) + " " + operator + " " + str(num2) + " = " + str(calculation) +"\n") 

                choice = input("To continue enter - yes or no: ") 
                if choice == "no":
                    print("See you next time!")
                    break

            except ValueError:
                print("Wrong key entered. Please key in a number")

            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print("You cannot divide by zero. Please try again!") 

        # OPEN FILE TO READ OPTION 
    elif process_choice == "F":

        file_name = input("Please enter the name of the file: ").lower
        path = Path("calculatortextfile.txt")
        contents = path.read_text()   
        print(contents)

        if file_name == "calculatorfiletext.txt":
            print("The file exists")
            with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
                    
                    lines = f.readlines()
                    print(lines)

        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError('No such file or directory')
        print("This file does not exist")

    file.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the code you've provided? You haven't mentioned anything wrong.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say 'The first input is not taking me to the options'? What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is using of `lower` and `upper`.

Those are functions, so you need to invoke them, like so:

```
process_choice = str(input("Enter 'C' to ...")).upper()
```

(by the way, str is not needed, `input` already returns a string.)

When you don't use the parentheses, what you assign to the variable 'process_choice' is actually a function.

To see this, you can try:

```
process_choice = str(input("Enter 'C' to ...")).upper

print(process_choice)
```

What you get is:

```
Enter 'C' to use calculator or 'F' to open file: C
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x000001C74A7090F0>
```

Which makes it clear what you actually did.

A function cannot be equal to any string or character, so you cannot proceed.

In your code, you check if it is either 'F' or 'C', but if it is neither, you are stuck in an infite while loop, try adding a last condition and check what the user wants to do next or, alternatively, get out of the loop with break.

```
if process_choice == "C": 
    ...
# OPEN FILE TO READ OPTION 
elif process_choice == "F":
    ...
else:
    print("bad option: " + process_choice)
    process_choice = input().upper()
```

Furthermore, you are closing the file in each iteration of the cycle, be aware, that starting with the second iteration, the file cannot be written to.

Answer (score 0):

*Call* the `upper` function: you forgot the parentheses.

```
process_choice = input("Enter 'C' to use calculator or 'F' to open file: ").upper()
```

(I've also removed the redundant `str(...)` call.)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing two parentheses at the end of

```
process_choice = str(input("Enter 'C' to use calculator or 'F' to open file: ")).upper()
```

Make sure you are always opening files with

```
with open('file_name', 'r/w/a/x') as 'alias':
```

Unless otherwise needed because they will close for you automatically after the necessary process is finished.

Comment: What is the problem with the indentation? I don't see any in the original code; your code does have an indentation problem.

Comment: I copy pasted the code from his code his indentation is off but it won't throw an error because the code never makes it that far. @9769953 if you scroll down you will see it at the aforementioned code.

Comment: The first three lines (`path = ...`, `contents = ...`, `print(...` are all on the same indentation level in the original code; not in your code.

Comment: You're still looking at the wrong portion of the code?? Observe the with open portion. @9769953

Comment: The `with open` portion is fine. The indentation is large, but not an error. And I see you've fixed your indentation error.